# Split line into multiple parts using regex

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-split

I have a string like

```
BK0001 My book (4th Edition) $49.95 (Clearance Price!)
```

I would like a way to split it into different parts like

```
[BK0001] 
[My Book (4th Edition)] 
[$49.95] 
[(Clearance Price!)]
```

I'm pretty new at regex and I'm using this to parse a line on a file. I managed to get the first part `BK0001` by using

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', 'BK0001 My book (4th Edition) $49.95 (Clearance Price!)';
```

then getting the `$part[0]` value but not sure on how to split it to get the other values.

Comment: have you used regex101 yet?  Great resource for both learning regexes and developing for a particular need .

Comment: Try spelling out the subpatterns. Say, `preg_match('~^(?<code>\S+)\s+(?<name>.*?)\s+(\$\d[\d.]*)\s*(?<details>.*)$~', $text, $matches)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EF0I6W/1).

Comment: @Dan Farrel I have but I don't use php and regex often, I code mostly in python and usually use string.split() for tasks such as these. This is one of those rare moments when I need regex and investing time learning it fully really a good option right now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: `learning it fully really a good option right now`  it's always good to learn Regex, most languages have some flavor of it and it's incredibly powerful and useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match the specific parts of the input string using a single pattern with capturing groups:

```
preg_match('~^(?<code>\S+)\s+(?<name>.*?)\s+(?<num>\$\d[\d.]*)\s*(?<details>.*)$~', $text, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EF0I6W/2). Actually, the last `$` is not required, it is there just to show the whole string is matched.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?<code>\S+)` - Group "code": one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<name>.*?)` - Group "name": any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<num>\$\d[\d.]*)` - Group "num": a `$`, then 1 digit and then 0+ digits or `.`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<details>.*)` - Group "details": any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

[PHP code](https://ideone.com/COIfJT):

```
$re = '~^(?<code>\S+)\s+(?<name>.*?)\s+(?<num>\$\d[\d.]*)\s*(?<details>.*)$~';
$str = 'BK0001 My book (4th Edition) $49.95 (Clearance Price!)';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $m)) {
    echo "Code: " . $m["code"] . "\nName: " . $m["name"] . "\nPrice: " .
         $m["num"] . "\nDetails: " . $m["details"]; 
}
```

Output:

```
Code: BK0001
Name: My book (4th Edition)
Price: $49.95
Details: (Clearance Price!)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using preg_match

```
$book_text = "BK0001 My book (4th Edition) $49.95 (Clearance Price!)";
if(preg_match("/([\w\d]+)\s+(.*?)\s+\\((.*?)\\)\s+(\\$[\d\.]+)\s+\\((.*?)\\)$/",$book_text,$matches)) {
    //Write code here
    print_r($matches);
}
```

$matches[0] is reserved for the full match string. You can find the split parts from $matches[1]...

```
Array ( [0] => BK0001 My book (4th Edition) $49.95 (Clearance Price!) [1] => BK0001 [2] => My book [3] => 4th Edition [4] => $49.95 [5] => Clearance Price! )

$matches[1] is "book number"
$matches[2] is "book name"
$matches[3] is "edition"
$matches[4] is "price"
$matches[5] is "special text"
```